# Python--creating a class that adds a key to dictionary object + attaches specific values

Tags: python, class, dictionary

First, here's my goal: I want to be able to add keys to a dictionary, and have those keys associated with a number of values. For example, I want to be able to have something like:

myDict['myKey1'].height
myDict['myKey1'].weight

I want to be able to add new keys to this, like myDict['myKey2'] such that I also have the option of attaching height and weight values to the new key as above.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
class Vividict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        value = self[key] = type(self)()
        return value
```

I've been using the above class to add new keys to dictionaries. I want to not only do this, but also input lists so that I can look up things like "height" and "weight" for the new key I add to my dictionary, by adding something like this into my class.

```
def __init__(self, list_of_vals, list_of_names):

    for x,y in zip(list_of_vals, list_of_names):
        self.(y) = x
```

I know the above is wrong, but I hope someone can see what I'm trying to achieve here. I want to define a class such that I can add a new key to a dictionary, and provide "list_of_vals" and "list_of_names" to attach some items to that dictionary key.

So, if I have "newKey" with list_of_vals=[1,2,3] and list_of_names=['height', 'weight', 'whatever'], I want to be able to do this:

```
myDict['newKey'].height = 1
myDict['newKey'].weight = 2
myDict['newKey'].whatever = 3
```

I hope this makes sense. I'm sort of trying to mimic what I can do in Matlab using structures.

Thanks!

----Update----

```
import collections

class Vals:

    def add(self, list_of_vals=[], list_of_names=[]):
        for val, name in zip(list_of_vals, list_of_names):
            setattr(self, name, val)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)

mydict = collections.defaultdict(Vals)
mydict['Foo'].add([1,2], ['height', 'weight'])
```

The above from tdelaney is in the direction I want to move. Thanks!

If I take the above code to add height and weight attributes. I want to be able to add to these if they exist. For example, something like:

```
mydict['Foo'].add([3,4], ['height'])
```

Such that is results in:

```
mydict['Foo'].height = [1,2,3,4]
```

In other words, I add [3,4] to the height attribute for the 'Foo' key.

Another feature I'd like to build into this class is to concatenate new rows into a numpy array each time I add new lists of numbers. For example, if I start with this:

```
mydict['Foo'].add([1,2], ['height', 'weight'])
```

And then do this:

```
mydict['Foo'].add([3,4], ['height', 'weight'])
```

I want to end with the following:

```
mydict['Foo'].height = [1,3]
mydict['Foo'].weight = [2,4]
mydict['Foo'].array = [1, 2; 3, 4]
```

In other words, I'm adding to the height and weight attributes each time, allowing me to add to growing lists with new data. At the same time, I want to the class to initialize an empty numpy array that we will add to row by row, such that each row contains height and weight, column 1 containing multiple height values, column 2 containing multiple weight values, and each row gets concatenated to the bottom of the array each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its more a question of the objects you put in the dictionary than the dictionary itself. With `myDict['myKey1'].height` for example, its the object in the dict that has a `height` attribute.

Since you can add attributes to most objects, you just need to define a very thin class to make those objects. You can have that class add attributes by lists. Then you can use a `collections.defaultdict` so that the objects are created dynamically as the dictionary is used.

```
import collections

class Vals:

    def add(self, list_of_vals=[], list_of_names=[]):
        for val, name in zip(list_of_vals, list_of_names):
            setattr(self, name, val)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)

mydict = collections.defaultdict(Vals)
mydict['Foo'].height = 1
mydict['Foo'].weight = 2
mydict['Foo'].add([1,2,3], ['a', 'b', 'c'],)
mydict['Bar'].add([10,11,12], 'def')
mydict['Baz'].something_else = 'hello'

assert mydict['Foo'].height == 1
assert mydict['Foo'].weight == 2
assert mydict['Foo'].a == 1
assert mydict['Foo'].b == 2
assert mydict['Foo'].c == 3


for name, obj in mydict.items():
    print(name, obj)
```

Result

```
Baz {'something_else': 'hello'}
Bar {'d': 10, 'f': 12, 'e': 11}
Foo {'c': 3, 'height': 1, 'b': 2, 'weight': 2, 'a': 1}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very much in the direction of what I want. I just edited the OP following up.

Answer (score 2):

I think idiomatic Python would avoid creating a custom class for something like this. Instead you could use a `namedtuple` for the dict entries, and just use a dict comprehension as your constructor:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple

>>> list_of_names = ["Clumsy", "Smurfette"]
>>> list_of_vals = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

>>> Smurf = namedtuple("Smurf", ("height", "weight", "whatever"))

>>> mydict = {k:Smurf(*v) for k,v in zip(list_of_names, list_of_vals)}
>>> print(mydict)

{'Clumsy': Smurf(height=1, weight=2, whatever=3), 'Smurfette': Smurf(height=4, weight=5, whatever=6)}
```

Comment: You and I have read this question very differently! I think OP wants to dynamically add attributes to objects in the list, not create objects with canned attributes like a `namedtuple`. It will be interesting to see how this plays out.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following?

```
class Vividict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        value = self[key] = type(self)()
        return value
    def __init__(self, list_of_vals=[], list_of_names=[]):
        for x,y in zip(list_of_vals, list_of_names):
           setattr(self, x, y)
```